# nginx, multiple domains, one server: reachable from some clients, 404 from others

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to host a friend's site on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.

I myself have multiple sites up at sub1.mydomain.com, sub2.mydomain.com etc. These are nodejs apps, each of them has a proxy-pass setup in an individual file like so:

```
server
{
    server_name sub1.mydomain.com;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:APP_PORT;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

the proxy_params file contains a bunch of stuff which I simply copied from some tutorial:

```
proxy_buffers 16 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Proxy '';
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;
```

This has worked for me.

Now I'm trying to point my friend's domain (her-domain.com) to another node app on my server for hosting her site.

```
server
{
    server_name her-domain.com;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:HER_APP_PORT;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

funnily, this does not seem to work right. If I use google DNS (8.8.8.8) on my computer, I can reach the app reverse-proxied to that domain just fine and look at the site it serves in my browser. But if I use a default DNS, nginx will serve a 404 page.

Since I can reach the server through that domain and nginx serves that 404, I assume it is an nginx config issue. I'm new to this stuff and don't know how to debug this.

Comment: Are you certain that the requests that result in a 404 are actually reaching your server? What do the logs say?

Comment: just double-checked - yes, they reach the server. e.g. visiting the domain in question from iPhone via LTE (no configurable DNS) I get this in nginx access log: `<<IPv6 address omitted>> - - [13/May/2018:16:21:28 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"`. --- possible that it's an ipv6 issue? when browsing from wifi here (where it works) it shows an ipv4 address in the access log. maybe has nothing to do with using a different DNS server...?

Comment: ah yes, turns out it was ipv6. added `listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;` to the conf and it works fine now.

Comment: Please add answers as actual answers, not as edits to the question, so that it is obvious that it is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had nothing to do with DNS.

The issue was that the nginx config did not handle IPv6 requests properly. changing the config to

```
server
{
    server_name her-domain.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:APP_PORT;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

fixed things.